# Как узнать значение в колонке с автоинкрементом?

Tags: c#

Есть DataTable dt. В нем создана колонка:

```
        DataColumn dcIndex = new DataColumn("ID");
        dcIndex.AutoIncrement = true;
        dcIndex.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
        dcIndex.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
        dt.Columns.Add(dcIndex);
```

Записи как добавляются, так и удаляются. Есть возможность узнать будущее значение в данной колонке при добавлении записи?

Comment: зачем Вам узнавать будущее значение?

Comment: А зачем вам это понадобилось? AutoIncrement нужен как раз для того, чтобы не думать о следующем значении. И даже если вы его узнаете, ни кто не может гарантировать, что когда вы захотите его применить - оно будет все еще актуально и допустимо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изначально при создании первой строки значение ID равно значению, указанному в свойстве `DataColumn.AutoIncrementSeed` и далее оно увеличивается на значение, указанное в свойстве `DataColumn.AutoIncrementStep`.

Следовательно, когда вы создаете новую строку

```
var row = table.NewRow();
Console.WriteLine(row["ID"]); // новое значение
```

поле ID уже содержит новое значение, кроме того это значение резервируется и сохраняется в `internal` свойстве `DataColumn.AutoIncrementCurrent`. Это позволяет добиться того, что каждое следующее значение инкремента уже не будет равно предыдущему.

---

Следуя этим рассуждениям у вас может возникнуть желание считать будущее значение ID как:

`текущее значение + DataColumn.AutoIncrementStep`

но я бы предостерег так делать т.к. нет ни какой гарантии, что после вызова метода `table.NewRow()` никто еще больше не создал новую строку и следовательно вычисления утратят актуальность.

Поэтому если вам нужно знать значение ID новой строки, вы можете просто создать эту строку:

```
var row = table.NewRow();
```

и добавлять (или вовсе не добавлять) ее в коллекцию `table.Rows` только тогда, когда это будет необходимо.

Answer (score 2):

Значение ID присваивается базой данных при вставке. Достать его можно, например, так:

```
INSERT INTO Table1(fields...) VALUES (...); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Выполнить такой запрос и получить значение ID можно, например, при помощи ExecuteScalar.

Comment: а применительно к DataTable это работает?

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, примерно так: `adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT ...", connection);`  Подробнее здесь (на английском): https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-identity-or-autonumber-values